# SQL - how to join data from two tables (adminer)

Tags: mysql

I am a complete newbie in sql... I am using w3s tutorial to learn some basic queries to help me at work. I'm trying to join two tables (order info about quantity, price and product ordered and the second one with client data - name, second name, phone number). My database is on Adminer 4.2.4. I wrote something like this (all the columns names are correct):

```
SELECT order_id.orders_products, quantity.orders_products, product_id.orders_products, firstname.orders_address, lastname.orders_address, phone.orders_address
FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN orders_address ON orders_address.order_id=orders_products.order_id;
```

but I'm still getting this error:

error in query (1054): unknown column 'order_id.orders_products' in field list

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: the sintax is tablename.columnname  not columnname.tablename

Comment: W3Schools? Really? Friends don't let friends....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
SELECT orders_products.order_id,
orders_products.quantity, 
orders_products.product_id, 
orders_address.firstname, 
orders_address.lastname, 
orders_address.phone
FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN orders_address ON orders_address.order_id=orders_products.order_id;
```

Comment: it helped! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @b.jablonski kindly accept the answer by clicking tick sign.